# How to use C++11 threading with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++11

Before I start I want to explain that I am a novice and that it's highly possible that I've missed something simple or that there's something simple that I just don't know about.

Using visual studio I wanted to get a bit of threading practice in but I can't get it to include  at the top of my code. I know that  is new to C++11 but I'm not sure if that's enabled for Visual Studio 2010 or if it isn't I'm not sure how I would go about doing that.

Here is a screenshot of my code:

[image: My Code]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot: C++11's Thread support library is not supported by the implementation of the C++ Standard Library shipped with VS2010. You should upgrade to VS2012 if you want to use it.

Alternatively, you could use [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread.html), which served as an inspiration for C++11's Standard Thread support library.

As a further option, you could consider purchasing the [Just.Thread](http://www.stdthread.co.uk/order.html) library, which provides a complete implementation and is available for VS2010 as well.

Comment: Ah thank you. I've been learning the SMFL and they have an implementation of threads but they said to use C++11 if you can. So I'll just learn theirs.
Thanks again!

Comment: @JosephLittle: note that there is a free version of VS2012 available, so upgrading (and using C++11 threads) should be very straightforward :)